# REST API documentation

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, api

I'm trying to use REST api of bitcoin core, i can do basic things such as getting latest block, or getting a transaction detail. But I couldn't find detailed explanation of the REST API. I checked the official release notes from [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md), but it's not complete as well.

I want to give an example, I couldn't find the information that I could get inputs and outpus of transaction when i request to `tx/hash/populate` instead of `tx/hash`, or i can get last block via `block/tip`, I want to find informations like this

I can see complete JSON RPC reference from [here](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/index.html), is there a REST equivalent of this?

Last but not least, shall I use the rpc, or is it okey to use the rest api?

thanks, dante